# XNA fullscreen: differing behavior based on buffer width

Tags: c#, xna, fullscreen

I'm having difficulty understanding how viewports are affected by fullscreen mode in XNA.  Everything works fine in windowed mode, but when I call `graphics.ToggleFullScreen()`, different stuff happens depending on the size of the backbuffer width prior to the call.  Here's what strikes me as the potentially pertinent code; it's split over two classes:

```
    // in the Game class
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    Viewport defaultViewport;
    Viewport mainViewport;

        // in the constructor:
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = Settings.BufferWidthInPixels;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = Settings.BufferHeightInPixels;            

        // in the initialize method, setting up the two viewports:
        defaultViewport = GraphicsDevice.Viewport;
        mainViewport = new Viewport();
        mainViewport.Width = (int)(Settings.DefaultBufferWidth * Settings.StretchFactor);
        mainViewport.Height = (int)(Settings.DefaultBufferHeight * Settings.StretchFactor);
        mainViewport.X = (Settings.BufferWidthInPixels - mainViewport.Width) / 2;
        mainViewport.Y = (Settings.BufferHeightInPixels - mainViewport.Height) / 2;

    // in the Settings class:
    public static readonly int DefaultBufferWidth = 800;
    public static readonly int DefaultBufferHeight = 480;
    // the following two variables are what I change to get different window sizes and hence different performance in fullscreen mode:
    public static readonly int BufferWidthInPixels = 1200;
    public static readonly int BufferHeightInPixels = 800;
    public static readonly float StretchFactor = Math.Min((float)BufferWidthInPixels / DefaultBufferWidth, (float)BufferHeightInPixels / DefaultBufferHeight);
    public static readonly Vector3 ScreenScalingFactor = new Vector3(StretchFactor, StretchFactor, 1);
    public static readonly Matrix BaseScreenSizeTransformation = Matrix.CreateScale(ScreenScalingFactor);
```

The only variables I am changing are `BufferWidthInPixels` and `BufferHeightInPixels`.  Here is some example behavior when they are:
(800, 480) -- the `defaultViewport` expands to fill the whole screen, while the `mainViewport` stays in the upper left corner.  No problems so far, although ideally I'd like the `mainViewport` to expand as well, or at least be centered if otherwise.
(800, 600) -- neither the `defaultViewport` nor the `mainViewport` change in size, though they are centered in the middle of the screen.  The rest of the screen becomes pure black.  Still good, although ideally the viewports would expand to fill the screen.
(1200, 800) -- the program hangs, turning my screen to a solid white-grey color.  After a moment the taskbar appears, but I have to go into Task Manager and end the process before I can get control of my computer back again.

Any insight on any of this would be appreciated; I can't figure out why fullscreen mode behaves so differently in these cases.  My monitor resolution is 1280x800, if that helps any (note that this is *not* the resolution that causes my computer to hang; fullscreen works as expected at `1280x800`).

Comment: Can you maybe not use real fullscreen and instead just increase viewport size to fill the screen?

Comment: It might not be related, but it's worth noting if you're working in fullscreen - an app that is about to go into fullscreen mode for the first time should do one of the following: A-set app resolution to perfectly match the screen resolution, B-ask the user in a windowed app which resolution to use. Some screens can be really picky about what resolutions you set on them. (Also, please always included a windowed option!)

Comment: Oh, also, use `graphics.IsFullScreen = true; graphics.ApplyChanges();` instead of `ToggleFullScreen`, to be sure settings are applied properly.

Comment: @mcmonkey4eva I can do these things (my eventual goal is to prompt the user for an appropriate screen resolution), but I'd still like my program to behave consistently regardless of which resolution was selected.  I've tried switching to the graphics.ApplyChanges() pattern you mentioned, but it hasn't made a difference.

Comment: Why do you have two viewports after all? Usually, the viewport should correspond with the backbuffer's width and height (starting at `(0, 0)`. Unless there are good reasons, you should not change this behaviour.

Comment: @NicoSchertler I have one viewport to be the background that (ideally) expands to fill the screen when the monitor's display doesn't match my program's native resolution.  If I'm targeting a 4:3 display but someone has a 16:9 monitor, I don't want the main part of my program to stretch, I just want the background to expand to fill up the extra space.  If there's a better/preferred way of doing this that doesn't involve two viewports, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Your graphics card can most likely only handle certian resolutions at full screen. You can iterate though the `SupportedDisplayModes` to find out what is supported by the device. Note this includes refresh rate so there will probably be duplicates.

```
foreach (DisplayMode mode in GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.SupportedDisplayModes) {

}
```